# Restlet multiple actions on one Entity

Tags: rest, restlet

I'm trying to figure out how to best lay out a set of Restlet APIs.
I have a User entity, which might have the standard CRUD operations, which fits nicely into rest, but there are other ones too like "reset password", or "terminate".

What is the best way to lay this out?

Here is what i was thinking:

```
/1.0/user/update        //perhaps this would just be a PUT on /1.0/user
/1.0/user/resetPassword //This would reset the password, but also send an email.
/1.0/user/terminate     //This might do some additional cleanup
```

Then I would make a UserResource that would really attach like this

```
/1.0/user/{actionType}
```

And the handling code might look like this (psuedo):

```
action = request.getAttributes().get("actionType");
if (action == "update") {
   do update
} elif (action == "resetpassword") {
   do resetpassword
} elif (action == "terminate") {
   do terminate
}
```

Really bad idea? Really ninja idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an OK idea.  If you want your application to be RESTful, you really have to provide links in the representation for your User resource, and document them as URIs that perform the selected actions.

The Sun Cloud API [does just this](http://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/CloudAPIVMRequests):

- GET a VM returns a representation VM including "controllers" that are URIs that perform functions (see [description of the VM media type](http://kenai.com/projects/suncloudapis/pages/CloudAPISpecificationResourceModels))
- Client knows about the media type, recognizes controllers (e.g. a VM provides "start", "stop" etc.
- URI of control resource for that particular VM is right there

So as you can see, if you use `/1.0/user/resetPassword` or `/1.0/user?op=resetPassword` or `/1.0/resetPassword?userId=xyzzy` is a bit irrelevant, since the client *really* shouldn't care, it merely follows links in representations.

Also, remember to use POST for such operations since they are generally not idempotent and they probably have side effects.

Comment: `/1.0/user?op=resetPassword` is far from RESTful, same for `/1.0/resetPassword?userId=xyzzy` neither are RESTful they are RPC over HTTP

Comment: @JarrodRoberson sorry, I respectfully disagree. If a client sees <form action="/1.0/user" method="get"><input type="hidden" name="op" value="resetPassword"><input type="submit" value="Reset"></form> and then goes and constructs a GET /1.0/user?op=resetPassword as a result, then it is as far away from RPC as you're going to get.  RPC vs REST is *not* in the format or structure of the URIs, it's all in _how_ your clients figure out the URIs, and whether they are hard coded in the client or discovered at run-time.

Answer (score 1):

How about these?

```
PUT /user/bob 
DELETE /user/bob/password 
DELETE /user/bob
```

and don't forget mogsie's point that the client should discover these URLs from some other document, it should not know them in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is so obvious to DELETE one's password in order to get a new one, if that's what it implied.  But it could be a nice, idempotent thing if each password were its own resource, re-deleting it would have no effect, since deletion of one password would generate a new password resource at a different URI.  Interesting idea.